# Eigenvalues after multiplication with permutation matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial, permutation-matrices

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix, and $P$ be permutation matrix of same size.
Does $A$ and $PAP$ have the same eigenvalues (or characteristic polynomial)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you mean $PAP$ or $P^{-1}AP$?

Comment: Isn't that the same? I mean P is its own inverse, so $PAP$ is the same as $P^{-1} AP$

Comment: No thats not the same $P=P^{-1}$ is not always true for permutation matices @HafizAjiAziz

Answer (score 1):

Since $P^\top = P^{-1}$ (it is not the case that $P = P^{-1}$), it follows that the matrices $A$ and $P^\top A P$ have the same characteristic polynomial and hence eigenvalues (the latter is called a *permutation similarity*).